# Using mkdir(), directory not being created

Tags: php, filesystems, mkdir

```
$ad_title = $_POST['title'];
$ad_content = $_POST['content-ads']; 
$ad_region = $_POST['region']; 

if (!is_dir("uploads/".$ad_region)) {
    // dir doesn't exist, make it
    mkdir("uploads/".$ad_region);
    echo "directory created!";
}
else {
    echo "directory already exist!";
}
```

I am making a site and I am developing it in localhost for now. My **save.php** file and the **uploads folders** where the codes above is saved in the local directory

```
localhost/system/modules/new/
```

When I relocated the **save.php** file and the **uploads folder** in the directory

```
localhost/system/
```

all seems to be working now. But I want it to work in the

```
localhost/system/modules/new/
```

directory for better organization. Any help on how to make it work?

Comment: Can you describe how it is *not working*?

Comment: @Phil: It wont create the directories in the uploads folder on this directory localhost/system/modules/new/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is ensure that the paths are where you think they are.

Try this out

```
$ad_title = $_POST['title'];
$ad_content = $_POST['content-ads']; 
$ad_region = $_POST['region']; 

// Make sure the "uploads" directory is relative to this PHP file
$uploads = __DIR__ . '/uploads';

$path = $uploads . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $ad_region;

// ensure that the path hasn't been tampered with by entering any relative paths
// into $_POST['region']
if (dirname($path) !== $uploads) {
    throw new Exception('Upload path has been unacceptably altered');
}

if (!is_dir($path)) {
    if (!mkdir($path, 0755, true)) {
        // you should probably catch this exception somewhere higher up in your
        // execution stack and log the details. You don't want end users
        // getting information about your filesystem
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Failed to create directory "%s"', $path));
    }

    // Similarly, you should only use this for debugging purposes
    printf('Directory "%s" created', $path);
} else {
    // and this too
    printf('Directory "%s" already exists', $path);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working now. What do you think was the cause of the problem?

Comment: @AnnaGee The only *real* change I made was making sure your `uploads` folder was relative to the PHP script by using the `__DIR__` constant as a path prefix. That and using the recursive option for `mkdir`

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative path `../` such as `mkdir("../uploads/".$ad_region)`

or use absolution path, such as `mkdir("/localhost/system/modules/new/".$ad_region)`

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: both. it wont produce any error but it wont create the folders neither. It just keep on printing "directory created!" but there are no directories created when I checked the uploads folder. I already checked if it is allowed to write on that directory. but still it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute file paths, like "/var/www/system/modules/new/$ad_region" (unix structure).

Or, for example, if your save.php file is in directory "system" and you want to create the directory in "system/modules/new/" you can do

```
mkdir("./modules/new/$ad_region");
```

There is a third parameter for mkdir, recursive, which allows the creation of nested directories. For the second parameter you can simple pass 0, for example

```
mkdir("./modules/new/$ad_region", 0, true);
```